# Detecting used terminal application (iTerm2)

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, terminal.app, iterm2

Can one detect what terminal application is being used? I want the actual application, not TERM env in the question.

I'd like to detect iTerm 2 / Terminal.app so I could set OSX specific keyboard mappings, otherwise PC.

(See [ALT+arrow moving between words in zsh and iTerm2](https://superuser.com/questions/427163/altarrow-moving-between-words-in-zsh-and-iterm-2) )

Comment: You could see if the application is "running" with

"ps -ax | grep iTerm"  

But I am not exactly sure how you would see if it was being "used"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to SSH forward local environment variables, as explained here:

http://groups.google.com/group/iterm2-discuss/msg/7cc214c487d31bc8

Answer (score -1):

I made the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$$ # Current PID
ps -f $$ | head -n 1 # Show the header of ps
while [ $pid -gt 0 ]; do # No more parent when we reach 0 (the kernel)
        ps -f $pid | tail -n +2 # ps current pid and remove header
        pid=$(ps -o ppid $pid|tail -n 1) # Get parent pid
done
```

It takes the current PID (`$$` in bash) and recursively gets the parent PID until we reach 0 (which is the kernel), printing the `ps -f` output along the way (and a header to start, with `ps -f | head -n 1`)

Two limitations I can think of:

1. If run over SSH, the parent will be `sshd` and not the graphical terminal application.
2. If executed in a separate script it will print that script too.

However you should be able to `grep` its output and detect if one of the parent process is iTerm.app or Terminal.app when run locally.

Comment: Why the downvote?